React Material UI Checkbox how to change checked
I have many checkboxes, and use them to set table columns.
It's look like
const [fields, setFields] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set(["name"]));

const handleChangeFilter = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (fields.has(event.target.value)) {
        fields.delete(event.target.value)
    } else {
        fields.add(event.target.value)
    }
    setFields(fields)
};

{filters.map((field) => {
    return (<FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox onChange={(event) => {
handleChangeFilter(event) }} value={field} checked={fields.has(field)} />} label={ field } />)   
})}

and fields changes as expected but checkboxs doesn't work.
I click and field add in fields but checkbox dosn't change.
Am I need state control for every field, but there're to many. I don't try to use Map in useState is it good idea?

You are trying to update the same fields state "fields.delete(..)", i think you should try same with a tempo variable or using call back from setFields. But you should not direclty mutate state

The issue with your checkbox not updating is that Set is a mutable object, and React doesn't detect changes in its state when you modify it directly. To solve this, you should create a new Set and update the state with this new Set.
const [fields, setFields] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set(["name"]));

const handleChangeFilter = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newFields = new Set(fields);
    if (newFields.has(event.target.value)) {
      newFields.delete(event.target.value);
    } else {
      newFields.add(event.target.value);
    }
    setFields(newFields);
};


Yep this work many thanks. I'm new in react so that simple problem make me stuck. Thanks again.

Set is mutable that means when there is any change in the set, it will not re-render the page. So you have to create new set from the existing set after adding and deleting.
const handleChangeFilter = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (fields.has(event.target.value)) {
        fields.delete(event.target.value);
    } else {
        fields.add(event.target.value);
    }
    setFields(new Set(fields));
};

